# UpdatePanel doesn't allow to fire button click inside gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and inside that I have below code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <!-- only your content that needs refreshing goes here -->

                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row"
                        onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonAdd" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have added update panel because when I click ButtonAdd button data in the gridview has been removed. But after I added below code button click event doesn't fire. Please suggest solution.

Comment: I would rethink the entire solution if I were you. GridViews don't play nicely with UpdatePanels. And UpdatePanels don't play nicely with anything, and GridViews are more difficult to work with on the client side than a plain HTML table. Instead of adding a row to the GridView, have you thought about having a dialog pop up that gets the values for the new row, then update the data source with the new data, then rebind the GridView?

Comment: What happens if you remove entire `<Triggers>` section. Button is already inside of UpdatePanel so this isn't needed

Comment: Why are you using `UpdatePanel` for a `Button`?

Comment: If I remove <Triggers>, no change at all. I need update panel to prevent from data loss when button click, it is inside gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Please place your whole gridview inside update panel and remove update panel inside and try..

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server"  >
     </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>

    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Get runtime error "A control with ID 'ButtonAdd' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'". Because button is inside gridview as a footer template.

Comment: Try not setting an async trigger and check?

Comment: Try not setting an async trigger doesn't work. Loss data when button click.

Comment: All the data I entered to gridview has been lost.

Comment: In which event you are binding your Gridview?In pageload?

Comment: I have a gridview, in page load it has no data and no rows. But there is a button to add rows dynamically. This row grows dynamically and when the user enters data and click the button, user faces data loss.